# Arbitrary .cmd script as screensaver in Windows 7 / XP

Tags: windows, opengl, jvm, cmd

I have a fullscreen OpenGL application, written in Scala. It is supposed to being launched as .cmd file that sets up classpath (some .class files, some of them are third-party libraries and optionally in .jars) and runs JVM with the right parameters. I'm wondering, is there an easy way to use this .cmd file as Windows screensaver? (without usual screensaver preview and settings dialog, they are not needed there) I guess I need to register the application somewhere? Is there any restriction on what file type it must be?

Comment: change the extension to .scr and then right click it -> install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a screensaver by doing as @Kevin suggested and right click the file and install (provided that this is a `.scr` file). Or you can copy the file straight to `C:\Windows` or sometimes `C:\Windows\system32`.

However, unless the file is a valid screensaver then it won't show up in the list of screensavers when you choose which one you want, so I think you are out of luck.

Unless you created your own screensaver, and then you might be able to launch the file from one of the events it has.